# Наследование в WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

мне нужно создать много UserControl, но у всех должен быть одинаковый метод который будут реализовывать уже наследники. я делаю так:
делаю базовый UserControl

```
    public abstract class WizForm : UserControl
    {
        public abstract bool ChekPage();
    }
```

затем наследую от него

```
    public partial class UserControl1 : WizForm
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public override bool ChekPage()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

в итоге с самой формой наследником визуально ничего сделать не могу, получаю ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как правильно наследовать чтобы можно было накидывать на форму компонентов ?

---

с данными классами вот так хочу

```
WizForm[] frm = { new UserControl1(), new UserControl1() };

foreach (WizForm w in frm)
{
     if (!w.ChekPage())
     {
          //...........
     }
}
```

Comment: Если правильно помню, вы не можете наследовать элементы WinForms. Обратитесь к документации.

Comment: Воспользуйся интерфейсом

Comment: @VoidStack, пробовал, не получилось

Answer (score 0):

сделал вот так и все получилось

базовый класс

```
    public class WizForm : UserControl
    {
        public virtual bool ChekPage()
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("На всякий случай");
        }
    }
```

наследник :

```
    [Designer(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Design.WindowsFormsComponentEditor))]
    public partial class UserControl1 : WizForm 
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public override bool ChekPage()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```